# How to write .trigger() code for the template?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table below which contains a textbox and next to the textbox  it contains a hyperlink known as "Open Grid". If the user clicks on this link, it opens up a grid and on this grid it displays number buttons from 3 - 26.

```
<table id="optionAndAnswer" class="optionAndAnswer">
    <tr class="option">
    <td>1. Option Type:</td>
    <td>
    <div class="box">
        <input type="text" name="gridValues" class="gridTxt maxRow" id="mainGridTxt" readonly="readonly" />
        <span href="#" class="showGrid" id="showGridId">[Open Grid]</span>
    </div>


    <table class="optionTypeTbl">
    <tr>

        <tr><td><input type="button" value="3" id="btn3" name="btn3Name" class="gridBtns gridBtnsOff">

        <input type="button" value="4" id="btn4" name="btn4Name" class="gridBtns gridBtnsOff">
        <input type="button" value="5" id="btn5" name="btn5Name" class="gridBtns gridBtnsOff">
        <input type="button" value="6" id="btn6" name="btn6Name" class="gridBtns gridBtnsOff">

        //...goes all the way to btn26
            </tr>

            </table>

            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now the code below is able to trigger one of the grid buttons to state that a grid button is clicked. This code is below:

```
$('#btn'+gridValues).trigger('click');
```

Now everything above is fine.

THE PROBLEM:

The issue I have is that a user can add a row containing the same template as the option control on top. But within this option and answer control, the user can change an option type if they wish by clicking on one of the grid buttons in this template. So my question is that how do I write the `.trigger()` to correctly point to a grid button within this template? If you look at the above code, it users the button's id, but if you look at code below which does the template, it doesn't contain an id, it simply just copies the option and control features from above into the template.

Below is the template:

```
function insertQuestion(form) {    

 var context = $('#optionAndAnswer');

    var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'>");
    var $options = $("<div class='option'>Option Type:<br/></div>");
    var $questionType = '';

    $('.gridTxt', context).each( function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var $optionsText = $("<input type='text' class='gridTxtRow maxRow' readonly='readonly' />")
    .attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
    .attr('value',$this.val())
    .appendTo( $options )
    .after("<span href='#' class='showGrid'>[Open Grid]</span>");

    $questionType = $this.val();

    });


    $td.append($options);
    $tbody.append($tr); 

}
```

UPDATE:

I have created a URL for this application [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text14.php). Please follow the steps to use the application and then you can see what is happening:

- Step 1: When you open application, you see a green plus button on the
  page, click on it and it will display a modal window.
- Step 2: In modal window there is a search bar, type in "AAA" and
  submit search, you will see a bunch of rows appear.
- Step 3: In the first row, you see under "Option Type" A-D, click on
  the "Add" button within this row, the modal window will close and you
  see in the grey textbox on right hand side that "Option Type" textbox
  equals 4 and it displays the Answer buttons A,B,C and D, this is
  because as you remember the option type for that row was "A-D".

Now this works fine but it only works for the top option and answer control, follow the steps below:

- Step 4: Click on the "Add Question" button, it adds a row underneath
  containing the details from the option and answer control on top.
- Step 5: Within the row you have just added, you see a green plus
  button on left hand side, click on this button and perform the same
  search "AAA" in search box.
- Step 6: This time select the last row by clicking on its "Add"
  button, the "Option Type" for this row is "A-G" so it should display
  "Answer" buttons A,B,C,D,E,F and G, but it doesn't do this, it still
  states "A,B,C,D".

So how do I change the answer buttons display in the option and answer control within one of the appended rows?

The `addwindow()` function you see in the view source in the application is the function which occurs after the "Add" button is clicked on. The "Add" button is in an included PHP script and the code for this button is below and with it are all the columns you see after you have performed a search in the modal window:

```
     echo "<table border='1' id='resulttbl'>
      <tr>
      <th class='questionth'>Question</th>
      <th class='optiontypeth'>Option Type</th>
      <th class='noofanswersth'>Number of <br/> Answers</th>
      <th class='answerth'>Answer</th>
      <th class='noofrepliesth'>Number of <br/> Replies</th>
      <th class='noofmarksth'>Number of <br/> Marks</th>
      </tr>";
      foreach ($searchResults as $key=>$question) {
        echo '<tr class="questiontd"><td>'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>';
        echo '<td class="optiontypetd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchOption[$key]).'</td>';
        echo '<td class="noofanswerstd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchNoofAnswers[$key]).'</td>';
        echo '<td class="answertd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchAnswer[$key]).'</td>';
        echo '<td class="noofrepliestd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchReply[$key]).'</td>';
        echo '<td class="noofmarkstd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchMarks[$key]).'</td>';
        echo "<td class='addtd'><button type='button' class='add' onclick=\"parent.addwindow('$question','$searchMarks[$key]','$searchNoofAnswers[$key]','$searchOption[$key]','$searchReply[$key]','$searchAnswer[$key]');\">Add</button></td></tr>";
}
      echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Please show rendered HTML (as seen in 'view source' in your browser), PHP is entirely irrelevant to client-side JavaScript.

Comment: I have changed the html from php to view source html in question

Comment: Could you give a jsFiddle example of what it's doing right now?

Comment: I don't see a hyperlink or its click handler.

Comment: give me time to put it in a fiddle :)

Comment: I can't put it in fiddle because need to connect to db, but I have included the url to application in the question with steps to follow so you are able to use the app and see for yourself what is happening. Please read the steps carefully and you can see what my problem is.

Comment: The statement `$('#btn'+gridValues).trigger('click');` appears within function `addwindow()`, which is not called, at least not from any script on the page. Is it called from an included script?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Yes addwindow is called from an included php script, it is called from the "Add" button when it is clicked, the code of the "Add" button I have included in the question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I must be the bearer of bad news. The problem you are having stems from the overall design. Your HTML and javascript really need a bottom-up overhaul with the aim of getting all javascript into a single $(function(){...}) structure, and thus into the same scope. To achieve this you will need to :

- Attach all event handlers in javascript in favour of the HTML attribute approach (currently hybrid).
- Purge the iFrame in favour of fetching previous questions via AJAX.

In the process you will also purge some duplicate click handling (plus button img and its `<a>...</a>` wrapper).

Then, you can start to find a solution to your problem :

- Delegate all event handling associated with the original "Option and answer" block to a container that is common to it and all future "Option and answer" blocks. The common container may be `document` but preferably something more specific. This appears to be partly achieved already.
- Ensure that all internal referencing within the original "Option and answer" block works with classes rather than ids. `.closest()` and `.find()` will be useful here.
- On clicking the "+" button, store a reference to the "Option and answer" block (eg. a jQuery object representing its container, discovered *relatively*). Easiest approach is to store this reference in a variable in the `$(function(){...})` scope. (Now you are benefiting from making all those structural changes). The "Add" buttons' click handler will use this reference to affect the correct "Option and answer" block.
- On "Add Question", use jQuery's `.clone(true, true)` to make a copy of the original block (then insert the clone into the DOM). If the other fixes have been applied, then all functionality (click handlers) will attach to the clone automatically.

I work quite quickly but it would still allow 1-2 days for this.

Here's how I would organise the javascript.

```
$(function() {
    // **********
    // Data area
    // **********
    var $$ = { // reusable static jQuery objects
        'optionTypeTbl': $('#optionTypeTbl'),
        'o_and_a_proto': $("#proto"),
        'o_and_a_extras': $("#extras"),
        'modal': $("#modal")
    },
    $o_and_a_section = null;

    // ******************
    // Utility functions
    // ******************
    function trim(str) {
        return str.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi, "") // removes leading and trailing spaces
            .replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ") // replaces multiple spaces with one space 
            .replace(/\n +/,"\n"); // Removes spaces after newlines
    }

    // ****************
    // Initial actions
    // ****************
    $$.modal.hide();
    $("input.gridBtns").removeClass("gridBtnsOn");
    $("input.answerBtns").removeClass("answerBtnsOn");
    $$.optionTypeTbl.hide();
    // code above makes sure all buttons start in the OFF state (so all button are white).

    // **********************************************
    // Handlers for elements inside the main window
    // **********************************************
    $(document).on('click', function() {
        $$.optionTypeTbl.fadeOut('slow');
    });
    $("input.gridBtns", $$.optionTypeTbl).on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $container = $this.closest('.optionAndAnswer');
        $container.find(".gridBtns").removeClass("gridBtnsOn");
        $this.addClass("gridBtnsOn");
        $container.find(".gridTxt").val($this.val());
        //$container.siblings('span[name=gridValues[]]').val($this.val()); // ???
        $container.find('.answerBtns').each(function(index) {
            if (index < Number($this.val())) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
    $$.o_and_a_proto.find(".showGrid").on('click', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $container = $this.closest(".optionAndAnswer");
        $("input.gridBtns").removeClass("gridBtnsOn");
        var value = $container.find(".gridTxt").val();
        //$("#btn" + value.replace(/\s/g, '')).addClass("gridBtnsOn"); //???
        $$.optionTypeTbl.appendTo($this.closest("div.box")).show().css({
            left: $this.position().left,
            top: $this.position().top + 20
        });
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $$.o_and_a_proto.find(".plusimage").on('click', function() {
        $o_and_a_section = $(this).closest(".optionAndAnswer");
        $$.modal.modal();
    });
    $$.o_and_a_proto.find(".answerBtns").on('click', function() {
        //btnclick(this); // ???
    });
    $("#addQuestionBtn").on('click', function insertQuestion() {
        $$.optionTypeTbl.hide().appendTo(document);//ensure this itinerant table is not cloned
        $$.o_and_a_extras.append($$.o_and_a_proto.clone(true,true).attr('id','')).find("span#plussignmsg").remove();
    });

    // **********************************************
    // Handlers for elements inside the modal window
    // **********************************************
    $$.modal.find("#close").on('click', function() {
        $.modal.close();
        return false;
    });
    $$.modal.find("form").on('submit', function() {
        var form = $(this).get(0);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'previousquestions.php',
            data: {
                'searchQuestion': 1,
                'questioncontent': trim(form.questioncontent.value)
            },
            type: "get",
            success: function(html) {
                $("#searchResults").html(html);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Something went wrong");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    $$.modal.find("#searchResults").on('click', 'button.add', function() {
        var $container = $(this).closest("tr");
        var g = $container.find("optiontypetd").data('g');
        var btn = $container.find("answertd").text();
        $o_and_a_section.find("input.gridTxt").val(g);
        if($o_and_a_section.closest("#detailsBlock").length) { //if is original Options and Answers section
            //do something ???
            //$('#btn'+g).trigger('click'); //???
        }
        $.modal.close();
    });
});
```

This works to an extent, but please note that it requires associated changes to the HTML and CSS.

Comment: @user1490145, I have added sample code to demonstrate what I mean. It's neither complete not fully tested but you can use it for reference.